# Is it better to use Associative arrays or standard arrays in this situation?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes with their labels that I'm outputting in a form. The html requirement is a bit more complicated so I'm going to loop through to make this less mundane.

However, I'm not sure if I use:

```
$array[] = array("Label1", "CheckboxHTML1");
$array[] = array("Label2", "CheckboxHTML2");
$array[] = array("Label3", "CheckboxHTML3");
$array[] = array("Label4", "CheckboxHTML4");

//output
foreach($array as $current)
{
    //complicated html
    echo "<label>$current[0]</label>$current[1]";
}
```

Or:

```
$array["Label1"] = "CheckboxHTML1";
$array["Label2"] = "CheckboxHTML2";
$array["Label3"] = "CheckboxHTML3";
$array["Label4"] = "CheckboxHTML4";

foreach($array as $key => $checkbox)
{
    //complicated html
    echo "<label>$key</label>$checkbox[1]";
}
```

Does one have any greater benefit over the other? I was worried with using associative arrays because some of the label strings are very long and I wasn't sure if this would cause any problems.

Comment: In practical terms you would not see not even the slightest difference in performance unless you had hundreds of thousands of elements, go for whatever feels more natural for you to write and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have any issues as far as the length of the key.  As a general rule of thumb, it's best to use associative arrays when you know you, as the developer, might want to access that data based upon its name in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to string size in PHP. [String can be as large as 2GB.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

I think it's ok to assume this applies for arrays to. I mean using string as key.

I guess you should go the way suits you best. I'm opting for associative array.

Answer (score 2):

You should just do whatever is most natural in each case. Associative arrays exist so that you can efficiently retrieve items by key; **if you intend to do that then use them**.

It's true that almost certainly long keys will slightly impact performance when the array is constructed, but the definition of "very long" is not the same for humans and compilers.